# Error: undefined columns selected

Tags: r, wildlife-ecology

My question is simple and hopefully can be answered quickly. I have a code in R that is for calculating home ranges. Everything works except one line of the code, which I've included here:

```
locoh <- lapply(dat, function(x) rhrLoCoH(x[ c("LONGITUDE", "LATITUDE")]))
```

The error I get is as follows:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(x, c("LONGITUDE", "LATITUDE")) : undefined columns selected
```

My guess is that I have messed up somewhere with my commas, but I'm not sure where or how to fix it.

Comment: right after `[` - `x[ , c('long', 'lat') ]`  , assuming you're selecting columns from a data frame?

Comment: That seemed to do the trick. I also needed to edit another section earlier:

Comment: `dat <- lapply(fls, read.table, sep = "/t", header = TRUE)` needed to be changed to `dat <- lapply(fls, read.table, sep = ",", header = TRUE)`

Comment: @orbl_soil, go ahead and answer the question if you'd like a  green check mark.

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19205806/undefined-columns-selected-when-subsetting-data-frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your comma right after `[` - `x[ , c('long', 'lat') ]` as you are selecting columns.

Comment: Please edit your answer and add more explanation, showing the problem code and the corrected code.